# Youtube API wont play when calling player.playVideo()

Tags: javascript, jquery, youtube

I'm trying to get a click on .iphone to play a video that I constructed using the youtube API.

It's in theory really simple. Click on .iphone then call function playVid() which executes player.playVideo() which should play the video but it doesn't.

I know I'm missing something so basic and I appreciate any help.

Thanks!

```
    <div class="img">
        <div class="iphone-container">
            <div class="iphone">
                <img src="<?php the_asset_dir() ?>/iphone.png" alt="" srcset="">
                <div class="vid">
                    <div id="player" class="vid-wrapper">
                            <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/Uv554B7YHk4?rel=0&amp;showinfo=0" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen>
                        </iframe> 
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <img src="<?php the_asset_dir() ?>/section2_image_d.png" alt="" srcset="">
    </div>
```

My JS is below. I am using jQuery to call the function PlayVid() which executes player.PlayVideo() which according to the youtube documentation should in theory play the video but it does not.

```
var tag = document.createElement('script'); 
tag.id = 'player';
tag.src = 'https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api';
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

var player;
function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('player', {
        events: {
        'onReady': onPlayerReady
        }
    });
}

function onPlayerReady(){
    $('.iphone').on('click', function(){
        console.log("yolo");
        playVid() ;
    });
}

function playVid() {
    player.playVideo();
}
```

Comment: Have you tried in Firefox? This may be a new Chrome issue/"feature".

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove your iframe and change your onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() for:

```
function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
  player = new YT.Player('player', {
    height: '360',
    width: '640',
    videoId: '8t3EHHhkC34',
    playerVars: { enablejsapi: 1, playsinline: 1, origin: 'http://localhost' },
    events: {
      'onReady': onPlayerReady
    }
  });
}
```